# Laravel livewire changes .csv file to .txt, how to fix it?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-livewire, laravel-excel

I am trying to import data from excel file.
when i upload .csv file using livewire it convert to .txt file.

*note: I am not sure if it is from Livewire or Laravel.*

here is my modal code for importing file:

```
<x-jet-modal maxWidth="sm" wire:model="showImportDialog">
    <form wire:submit.prevent="import" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <div class="text-lg">Import Users</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" wire:model="users" name="users" id="users" />
        </div>
        <x-jet-button type="submit">Import</x-jet-button>
    </form>
</x-jet-modal>
```

and this is my livewire component:

```
...
use WithFileUploads;

public $users;

public function import()
{
    dd($this->users); // originalName: "W4K99h75YVHSou815dV0fErWMLzZ75-metaUUNTX1VzZXJzXzIwMjEtMDktMTQgMTdfNDdfNTMuY3N2-.txt"
    $validated = $this->validate([
        'users.*' => 'required|file|mimes:xls,xlsx,csv',
    ]);

    dd($validated); // it displays "[]"
}
...
```

when I dd() before validation shows this:

[image]

*update 1:*

when I did this:

```
dd($this->users->getClientOriginalName());
```

it shows:

```
Users_2021-09-14 17_47_53.csv
```

*Update 2:*

livewire config file:

[image]

Comment: can you provide the temporary_file_upload rules in config/livewire.php file?

Comment: @MdSomir thanks, I update the question and provided livewire config file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation for this: [How to store csv file laravel 5 php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569475/how-to-store-csv-file-laravel-5-php)

But basically, you have to specify the type of file using `->storeAs($path, $filename . '.csv')`.
Then laravel will save it like a CSV file; otherwise, it will turn the file into .txt.